# Using the standard/output stream as string input/output

Tags: java, io, standard-library

I have  an assignment stating that "You can assume that input will come from standard input in a stream. You may assume that the markers have access to all standard libraries".

How do I go about reading several lines/inputs and saving all the inputs as one string and then outputting that string from a function?

Currently this is my function, but it's not working properly, at one stage it wasn't reading more than one line and now it doesn't work at all.

```
public static String readFromStandardIO() {

    String returnValue = "";

    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    System.out.println("Reading Strings from console");

    // You use System.in to get the Strings entered in console by user
    try {
        // You need to create BufferedReader which has System.in to get user
        // input
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        String userInput;
        System.out.println("Enter text...\n");
        while (!(reader.readLine() == reader.readLine().trim())) {
            userInput = reader.readLine();
            returnValue += userInput;
        }

        System.out.println("You entered : " + returnValue);
        return returnValue;

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: If it's not working at all, I'd recommend pitching an e.printStackTrace() in your catch block and see if you get any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `reader.readLine()` three different times, so you'll end up comparing two completely different strings and then recording yet another one.

Also, it's generally frowned upon to compare strings using == (as comparing Objects with == asks if they are the same actual object (yes, Java's forgiving in that regard with strings, but it's still frowned upon)).

You'll need to do something more akin to:

```
public static String readFromStandardIO() {

    String returnValue = "";

    System.out.println("Reading Strings from console");

    // You use System.in to get the Strings entered in console by user
    try {
        // You need to create BufferedReader which has System.in to get user
        // input
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput;
        System.out.println("Enter text...\n");
        while (true) {
            userInput = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Finally got in here");
            System.out.println(userInput);
            returnValue += userInput;
            if (!userInput.equals(userInput.trim())) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("You entered : " + returnValue);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return returnValue;

}
```